# Seam Carving compute cost in one loop in python

Tags: python, seam-carving

How to compute the energy cost for Seam Carving in one loop iterating through the rows for python?
[Seam Carving Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving)
Like the Dynamic programming in wiki ,I need the min_cost on the last row for possible three cell, and store the cost and path.

And , it is very slow by using two loop , so anyone know how to make it more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numba.jit to (possibly) speed up calculations, provided you respect the correct typing. There is no way to avoid 2 loops in a dynamic programming, however you can take a look at improved seam carving (which also yields better results in general)

https://github.com/axu2/improved-seam-carving
https://medium.com/@avik.das/improved-seam-carving-with-forward-energy-88ba84dab7e

```
from numba import jit 

@jit
def calc_seam(img):
   ...
```